# What baud rate should I set for bluetooth TTY to Xbox controllers?

Tags: macos, command-line, bluetooth, screen

I'm trying to do screen tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port 9600 on my mac, but I'm not sure about my baud rate. How can I determine this? It's just giving me a "Cannot open line" error.

I'm trying to view output from an Xbox controller.

Comment: are you sure this has anything to do with Apple ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Well screen is apple command

Comment: great, so you can tell us what Mac and what OSX

Comment: @Buscar웃 It's Mac OS Mojave

Comment: check the information on the Incoming port `ls /dev/cu.*` this will tell you if your driver is working

Comment: @Buscar웃 Why? I already "ls" in that directory which is how I found tty.Bluetooth

Comment: ok, so do you see  your device listed

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yeah. I'm saying it's giving me Cannot open line error

Comment: `/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port` or what ? show me what you see with `ls /dev/cu.*`

Comment: @Buscar웃 I see: /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port. But since I generally use tty, I use that instead

Comment: that one is standard (I see it as well without anything plugged in), it is not your serial port (ID) for tty uses. you need to see the `/dev/cu.usbserial` with the right driver and plugged in.

Comment: @Buscar웃 What do you mean? So it's possible to open screen session to connect to bluetooth device from what I've been doing, but only with "cu" instead?

Comment: what I am saying is you do not have/see the `/dev/cu.usbserial` but you can try the `screen /dev/cu.usbserial 9600` to confirm

Comment: @Buscar웃 Why do I need that? I just want to interface with a bluetooth device, not a usb device

Comment: I just tried it. Says no such file or directory

Comment: sorry, I run out of space to continue commenting but before leaving, the standard baud rates are 300, 1200, 9600 or 19200

Comment: @Buscar웃 There are many more baud rates than that, and I am doubtful if my problem even has to do with the wrong baud rate. So, is there a way to figure out which baudrate my bluetooth device is, when I pair it to my computer? I just need to know this to test my theory of the wrong baud rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What baud rate should I set when using screen tty for Bluetooth?

Baud rate isn't dependent on *how* you connect to a serial console whether it be via bluetooth or hardwire.  It has to do with how fast the host (in this case the XBox controller) is sending bits through the [UART (Universal Asynchronous Receiver Trasmitter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter)

What matters here is that you match the [two UART settings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Settings) with the XBox controller.  Those settings are:

- Baud (bit rate)
- Serial Port Parameters

  - Data bits
  - Parity bits
  - Stop bits

**Baud** is the speed at which you're going to transfer data.  Common values are 9,600, 28.8K, 56K, or 115.2K (or more commonly as known 115,200).  Your XBox console will likely be either 9600 or 115200.

The **Serial Port Parameters** (or "Configuration") defines how each block of data is to be send/received.  This must match or you will get garbled info.  Common values are:

- 8-N-1 or "eight-none-and-one" for 8 data bits, no parity bits, and 1 stop bit
- 7-E-1 or "seven-even-and-one" for 7 data bits, an even number of logical ones, and 1 stop bit

#### TL;DR

To launch `screen` and set your communication parameters, use the following syntax:

```
$ screen <device> [speed],[config]
```

(You can get the device name by listing the contents of `/dev/cu.*` *after* you plug in the Bluetooth serial adapter)

So, in your case, assuming 9600 baud and 8N1 configuration, use the command:

```
$ screen /dev/cu.usbserialdevice 9600,cs8
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download Bluetooth Explorer as part of the 'Additional Tools for Xcode' package that's available (registration required) at

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Go to that link, then search for 'Additional', and find the Additional Tools package for the latest version of Xcode (you don't actually need Xcode installed to use the Bluetooth Explorer app!).

That will allow you more in depth BT analysis and information.